# Denying access to source folder

Tags: laravel, compilation, xampp, production-environment

I developed a project in Laravel and the files are served from htdocs files in the XAMPP Server. Is there any way that i could restrict the access to htdocs. Or is there a way that the whole project would be compiled and minified so no one can see the source. (Like Angular production version).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set public folder in you project as document root?

Comment: Yes. It it set as document root